# Compiler arm-none-eabi-gcc v4.9.3 optimizes away operations to pointers

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, volatile

When I compile my code for my STM32F429 CPU everything works fine when I use the `-O0` flag but as soon as I use a higher optimization `(-O1, -O2, and -O3)` the code breaks.
I'm using the CMSIS+HAL libraries from ST and some basic code.

The problem is that even though `*uart_irq` is defined as `volatile` the `if (uart_irq && uart_irq->SOURCE == IRQ_SOURCE_UART)` in the main loop is **never evaluated**.
I have tried to define `uart_irq` as a `volatile void *` without success.
The only thing that work is if `uart_irq` is defined as a `volatile uint32_t` and the integer is cast to a `irq_instance` when used as the compiler wont remove that during optimization.

I would be happy if anybody would shed some light on the problem.

- Is this supposed to be the standard behavior?
- Is this a known bug in the compiler?

main.h

```
#define API_COMMAND_SIZE 6
typedef struct irq_instance_s
{
    uint8_t SOURCE;
    uint8_t TYPE;   
    uint8_t *CONTEXT;  
    uint8_t SIZE; 
} irq_instance;
extern volatile irq_instance *uart_irq;
```

main.c
The `receive` pointer is freed inside `hande_command`

```
#include "main.h
volatile irq_instance *uart_irq = 0;

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t *receive  = 0;
    <Initialize stuff>

    /* Initialize first UART recieve */
    receive = malloc(API_COMMAND_SIZE);
    while (HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, receive, API_COMMAND_SIZE) == HAL_BUSY);
    /* Program Main loop */
    while(1) {
        if (uart_irq && uart_irq->SOURCE == IRQ_SOURCE_UART) { /* <---- Problem is here */
            handle_interrupt(uart_irq);
            free((void *)uart_irq);
            uart_irq = 0;
        }
     }
}
```

stm32f4xx_it.c
The `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` are called after each successful UART receive.

```
#include "main.h"

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    uint8_t *receive  = 0;
    uart_irq          = calloc(1, sizeof(irq_instance));
    uart_irq->SOURCE  = IRQ_SOURCE_UART;
    uart_irq->CONTEXT = huart->pRxBuffPtr - huart->RxXferSize;
    uart_irq->SIZE    = huart->RxXferSize;
    uart_irq->TYPE    = IRQ_TYPE_COMMAND;

    receive = malloc(API_COMMAND_SIZE);
    while (HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, receive, API_COMMAND_SIZE) == HAL_BUSY);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand why you want it to be volatile. Do you want the pointer or the pointee to be volatile?

Comment: `uart_irq` is not declared `volatile`, but the object it points to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
volatile irq_instance *uart_irq
```

says that the thing pointed to by uart_irq is volatile. But

```
if (uart_irq && uart_irq->SOURCE == IRQ_SOURCE_UART)
```

is looking at the pointer itself, not the thing that's being pointed to.  If the pointer itself is also volatile, which looking at your code it is, then declare it like this:

```
volatile irq_instance * volatile uart_irq
```

Comment: So the first `volatile` says that the struct is volatile, and the second says that the pointer itself is volatile.
What happens if you write `volatile irq_instance volatile *uart_irq` ?

Answer (score 1):

If I read this correctly then you are changing the `uart_irq` inside the IRQ handler and it's this change of pointer value that the optimizer cannot see in the regular program flow and hence is optimizing away.

The correct declaration for a volatile pointer is `irq_instance * volatile uart_irq`. The way that you have declared it tells gcc that the value pointed to by the pointer is volatile. If this is also the case then you may combine the two with `volatile irq_instance * volatile uart_irq`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `uart_irq` is `volatile`, not just what it points to...  Define it this way:

```
extern irq_instance * volatile uart_irq;
```